# Combining hot encodings from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I am trying to combine results of a data frame df2 column into an anther data frame that is called df in order to hot encode it and add to the pipeline of the df**

Question What would be the proper order and method to combine them?

**My Thoughts**

To combine the results of my topic labeling data frame df2 by the column df2['Topic Label'] in order to hot encode it and then add it to the recommender as a 4th factor.

**What I tried**

I have two separate working data frames so I create df2 in order to get the results of df2['Topic Label'] first so I can combine it to the other data frame that is just df. Both of these data frames are fully working before this.

**The Code**

[Jupyter Notebook at github](https://github.com/taylorjohn/Simple_RecSys/blob/master/dnd-hybrid-part1-content-topic.ipynb)  Full code

[excel for data at github](https://github.com/taylorjohn/Simple_RecSys/blob/master/dnd-dataframe.xlsx)  Dataset

```
df = pd.read_excel('dnd-dataframe.xlsx', sheet_name=0, usecols=['name', 'weapons','herotype','spells']) Toy Dataset
df.head(30)

dummies1 = df['weapons'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
dummies2 = df['spells'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
dummies3 = df['herotype'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
dummies4 = df2['Topic Label'].str.get_dummies()

genre_data = pd.concat([df, dummies1, dummies2, dummies3] + [df2, dummies4], axis=1)
```

[image: topic labels]

[image: recommender]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After some more reading and trying I figured it out.**

First I took the data frame (df2) that I want to add to the existing one for the final data frame.

so I created the one-hot encoding or dummies for the topics

```
dummies4 = df2['Topic Label'].str.get_dummies()

dummies4.head()

adventure   lucky   musical     pedigree    religion    survivor    tricky
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

**then I concatenated it using the dummies4 into the df from df2**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```
genre_data = pd.concat([df, dummies4], axis=1).reindex(df.index)
genre_data.head()
```

And finally did the orginal df get dummies but this time last on order instead of first

```
    name    herotype    weapons     spells  adventure   lucky   musical     pedigree    religion    survivor    tricky
0   bam     Bard    Dagger, sling, club     Transmutation, Enchantment  0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   niem    Sorcerer    light crossbow, battleaxe   Necromancy  0   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   aem     Paladin     Greataxe    Abjuration, Conjuration     0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   yaeks   Rogue   club, battleaxe     Conjuration, Evocation, Transmutation   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
4   jeeks   Druid   Dagger, Greataxe    Evocation, Transmutation, Necromancy    0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

**Finally,** now that both the recommender and the topic labels are hot encoding I can now run the hybrid and I get a slightly more interesting result. That take the topic into consideration in sorting the results.

[image]